# What is the difference between Point and Pixel and why is Pixel unaffected by DPI?

Tags: qt, pyqt5, pixel, dpi

I created a small script to draw some text on an image, the purpose of this code is to illustrate that the font size of the drawn text is unaffacted by `self.image.setDotsPerMeterX(75)`, `self.image.setDotsPerMeterY(75)` and `self.image.setDevicePixelRatio(1)` when using `setPixelSize(25)`. However the drawn text is affected by `dpi` when using
`setPointSizeF(25)`. My question is, **"What is the difference between Points and Pixels, and why is Pixel font unaffected by dpi?"**

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont, QImage, QPainter
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget

DEFAULT_WIDTH = DEFAULT_HEIGHT = 250


class QPainterWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = QImage(DEFAULT_WIDTH, DEFAULT_HEIGHT, QImage.Format_RGB32)
        self.image.fill(Qt.green)
        self.image.setDevicePixelRatio(1)
        self.image.setDotsPerMeterX(75)
        self.image.setDotsPerMeterY(75)
        painter = QPainter(self.image)

        point_size_font = QFont('arial')
        point_size_font.setPointSizeF(25)
        painter.setFont(point_size_font)
        painter.drawText(0, 0, DEFAULT_WIDTH//2, DEFAULT_HEIGHT//2, Qt.AlignCenter, "point font text")

        pixel_size_font = QFont('arial')
        pixel_size_font.setPixelSize(25)
        painter.setFont(pixel_size_font)
        painter.drawText(0, 0, (DEFAULT_WIDTH//2) + 100, (DEFAULT_HEIGHT//2) + 100, Qt.AlignCenter, "pixel font text")

        painter.end()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.drawImage(0, 0, self.image)
        painter.end()


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(DEFAULT_WIDTH, DEFAULT_HEIGHT)
        self.setCentralWidget(QPainterWidget())


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
app.exec()
```

Comment: Does [this](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/scalability.html#handling-pixel-density) section of the docs help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A raster image is normally composed of a grid of *pixels*<sup>[1]</sup>, which are the smallest ***el**ement* of a ***pict**ure* ("pix"-"el") that shows some color, and will compose the final image in its entirety.

The "size" of a raster image is always measured in the length of those pixels for each dimension. But that's not an *physical* size (like meters or inches), it's an absolute unit of quantity.

For example, a standard (*real*<sup>[2]</sup>) HD screen has a *physical resolution* of 1920x1080 pixels. It means that that screen has a *physical* grid of leds (or whatever) that are exactly put in 1920 columns and 1080 rows.
But you can actually have screens with that same resolution that are 2 meters wide or 20 even centimeters (and less).

If you create an image that has the above resolution, and draw a text that uses a font that is set for a *pixel* size of 1080, then you'll see the text filling the whole image vertically, but that text would be 1 meter tall in the first screen, or 10 cm in the second.

When you specify the "setDotsPerMeter", you're setting the *density* of pixels in a physical reference, as the documentation [explains](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#setDotsPerMeterX):

> Sets the number of pixels that fit [...] in a physical meter.

If you draw the text setting the font size in *points*, the result will change depending on the setting of those "dots per meter".

Now, here is where things become confusing, so let's put your code on hold and imagine a "virtual" situation.

I am an artist and I want to create a project that shows a black square using grids. I have two groups (`a` and `b`) of 4 square canvasses:

1. a 1 meter wide canvas, with grids 10cm wide (100 "pixels");
2. a 10 centimeter wide canvas, with grids 1cm wide (again, 100 "pixels");
3. a 1 meter wide canvas, with grids 1cm wide (10000 "pixels");
4. a 10 centimeter wide canvas, with grids 1mm wide (10000 "pixels" as above);

Then, I start with the first group, and I will paint in black just 1 "cell" of that grid, as they were "pixels", which is the same as using `font.setPixelSize(1)`: a 1-pixel square.
I will get squares that, for each canvas, will be wide:

1. 10cm;
2. 1cm;
3. 1cm;
4. 1mm;

Now, the second group. The aim is to *always* get a 10x10cm square, just like using `font.setPointSize(1)` (and "point" is the reference). This means that I'll need to paint in black:

1. just one cell in the grid;
2. *all* cells in the grid;
3. 100 cells (10x10);
4. *all 10000* cells in the grid;

And this is because each one has its `DotsPerMeter` based on the grid size, and each "dot" is the expected result of a 10x10cm square:

1. 10;
2. 100;
3. 100;
4. 10000;

Back to our case, you have to also consider three aspects: the density of the image (and the default OS settings), the device pixel ratio (which could differ from the `DotsPerMeter` settings) of the paint device (the image), and the density of the screen in which it's visualized. The concept is similar to our *view*: the resolution of the image doesn't change on the depending on the screen of your screen, and *none* of them changes if you look at that screen from 1 meter or you put it just 10cm before your eyes.

Also, consider that the OS uses a DPI setting used to display text (when its size is set with *points*, not with pixels) based on various aspects:

- default settings (the standard convention is 96 DPI);
- screen settings;
- system-based screen settings;
- text scaling (for modern systems);

Then, setting the density (`DotsPerMeter`) of an image, as explained in the documentation:

> does not change the scale or aspect ratio of the image when it is rendered on other paint devices.

So, in conclusion, as the QFont documentation explains, you should always use the point size, *unless* you explicitly need a pixel reference.

For images, that could be fine, since those values are absolute to the actual resolution of the image.
But for *visualization* purposes, that doesn't work well: you either get a [pixelated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixelation) result, or the text will be too small to be read.

*Notes:*

<sup>[1]</sup> See [this answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/199/point-vs-pixel-what-is-the-difference) on GraphicDesign and [Pixel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel) on WikiPedia.

<sup>[2]</sup> This is valid only for *computer* screens, TV screens often *support* HD resolutions, but actually have smaller physical resolutions and use downscaling, since it's cheaper to have a processor that scales the image than producing screens with twice the pixels in the same *size*: many standard HD televisions actually use 1366x768 screens (1'049'088 pixels against 2'073'600).

Comment: Note: Minutes after posting this answer, I realized some inaccuracies (for instance, the "point" unit using the [Pica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pica_(typography)), for which I'll probably improve my explanation after further studying) and other small issues in my explanations; nonetheless I believe it is still a valid answer in concept. I'll keep reading and improving it, but I'll be glad to have further input from other users in comments.

Comment: sorry if I could just clarify, when you say `a 1 meter wide canvas, with grids 10cm wide (100 "pixels");`. Do you mean the width and height is 1 meter, 10cm wide grids but the entire grid has 100 pixels. I am sometimes reading this as 100 pixels in the full width or on the grid. Hence 10 pixels on the width with 10 rows, making 100 pixels. Also when you discussed `For example, a standard (real[2]) HD screen has a physical resolution of 1920x1080 pixels`, we went from width (20cm wide) but the example after that gave the example in height, are all your examples square? Thanks again

Comment: @J.Doe Yes, it's common expression to use the width in pixel to refer to screen sizes, since it's an easier reference (2K vs 4K instead of ~2M vs ~8M), but, yes, the "grids 10cm wide" means that each cell is 10x10cm and my `100 "pixels"` refers to the total amount of pixels. For simplicity of explanation, in my example I used a square grid (same number of rows and columns), so that numbers are simpler, but screen resolutions are never square, they are about 2×1 (16:9, 21:9, etc), meaning that if the screen is 20cm wide, it's about 10cm tall.